# Why can't I use Sequence to perform a Select like task?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Suppose I wanted to write down a list of $p^2$, for $p$ a prime between $1$ and $20$. I would expect

```
Table[If[PrimeQ[k], k^2, Sequence[]], {k, 1, 20}]
```

to work. In fact, this produces,

```
{Null, 4, 9, Null, 25, Null, 49, Null, Null, Null, 121, Null, 169, Null, Null, Null, 289, Null, 361, Null}
```

Why does this happen, and is there a variant which does work the way I expect?

Of course, I can just do

```
Map[(#^2) &, Select[Range[20], PrimeQ]]
```

I don't have a real reason to avoid this, but it feels less readable to me.

UPDATE: Given the answers I'm seeing, I should point out that this is meant to be a toy example and the actual code involves boolean functions much messier than `PrimeQ[]`, for which there is no analogue of `Prime[]` available. But Szabolcs answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Just in case you weren't already aware of the enhanced abilities of `Table[]`: `Table[k^2, {k, Select[Range[20], PrimeQ]}]` also works well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that `Sequence[]` expands already inside the `If[ ... ]` because `If` does not have the `SequenceHold` attribute.  `If[False, <<something>>]` (i.e. missing third argument) will evaluate to `Null`.

Just use

```
Table[If[PrimeQ[k], k^2, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {k, 1, 20}]
```

Comment: ...or use the "vanishing function" variation: `Table[If[PrimeQ[k], k^2, ## &[]], {k, 20}]`

Comment: @J.M. the vanishing function is very useful in specific circumstances but I personally find it less transparent than the alternatives. Also, it comes with a certain amount of overhead--here, for example, it's almost 50% slower than using `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Szabolcs explained the why, just an example of something readable you can use instead:

```
Table[Prime[n]^2, {n, PrimePi[20]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this more readable?

```
Select[Prime[Range[20]], # < 20 &]^2
```

Or probably even better would be

```
Prime[Range[PrimePi[20]]]^2
```

Comment: Or, perhaps, `myfn2[x_?PrimeQ] := x^2;
myfn2[x_] := Sequence[];
Table[myfn2@k, {k, 1, 20}]`