# Create list via checkboxes

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation

I am trying to achieve the following: Three (dynamically updated) `Checkboxes` (a, b and c) can be toggled on or off individually. Depending on their status, a resulting list shall be set to `{a,b,c}`, `{a,c}`, `{b,c}`, etc.

I am currently using the following code:

```
{"a:" Checkbox[Dynamic[a]],
 "b:" Checkbox[Dynamic[b]], 
 "c:" Checkbox[Dynamic[c]], 
Dynamic[{If[a, "a",], If[b, "b",], If[c, "c",]}]}
```

But this yields, depending on the setting, a list of the kind `{a,b,Null}`, etc. - that is, if a checkbox is set to `False`, the list element is set to `Null` rather than left out entirely.

Is there any way to achieve my goal in a not-so-cumbersome way (i.e., avoiding something like a 8-cases `Piecewise` or `Which` function)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, I think this might be a duplicate, see link below, but here we go:

In your setup, you want to make sure that the `If` evaluates to something meaningful (as you can see, just leaving the 3rd argument blank yields `Null`).

Thus, it makes sense to use either `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` or shorter, just `##&[]`:

```
{"a:" Checkbox[Dynamic[a]], "b:" Checkbox[Dynamic[b]], 
"c:" Checkbox[Dynamic[c]], 
Dynamic[{If[a, "a", Unevaluated[Sequence[]]], If[b, "b", ## &[]], 
If[c, "c", ## &[]]}]}
```

Then, if the `If`-clause evaluates to false, you are returned an unevaluated sequence, which will be used in further output (in your case, the list).

You might ask: why the `Unevaluated`? See Szabolcs explanation here: [Why can't I use Sequence to perform a Select like task?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/why-cant-i-use-sequence-to-perform-a-select-like-task) (and note J.M.'s comment there, for the vanishing function)

As mentioned in the comments, you might e.g. use `Pick` for this task:

```
{"a:" Checkbox[Dynamic[a]], "b:" Checkbox[Dynamic[b]], "c:" Checkbox[Dynamic[c]],     
Dynamic@Pick[{"a", "b", "c"}, {a, b, c}]}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Should I delete my comments above, since they don't add anything to the question?

Comment: well, why not, let's clean up a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

It seemed that the question is asking how to display a list of selected strings.  It seemed quite possible that underlying that, is how to pick variables in the same way, which takes a little more care.    (You can substitute inside the `Dynamic[resultingList = ...]` the expression `{a, b, c}` or `varList` for `labelList`, if you want the list to be the variables.)

```
labelList = {"a", "b", "c"};
varList := {a, b, c};
```

## CheckboxBar

You can use `CheckboxBar`, but the check boxes have to appear together.

```
x = {};
{CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x], {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}], 
 Dynamic[resultingList = labelList[[Sort@x]]]}
```

[image: CheckboxBar]

## Checkbox

If you want to place the check boxes wherever, then you can use `Part`s of a `List`.

```
y = ConstantArray[False, 3];
{"a:" Checkbox[Dynamic[y[[1]]]], "b:" Checkbox[Dynamic[y[[2]]]], 
 "c:" Checkbox[Dynamic[y[[3]]]], Dynamic[resultingList = Pick[labelList, y]]}
```

More succinctly, and with `Row` to format the label-check-box pairs:

```
pickedVars = ConstantArray[False, 3];
{MapIndexed[Row[{#1, Checkbox[Dynamic[pickedVars[[First[#2]]]]]}] &,
  {"a: ", "b: ", "c: "}], 
 Dynamic[resultingList = Pick[labelList, pickedVars]]}
```

[image: Row of Checkboxes]

Technically in your original code you're using `Times` to format them.  It seems to work because the order that *Mathematica* puts the factors in happens to be the one you desire.  You can also use `Labeled` instead of `Row`, as well as several [other commands](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/UserInterfaceStructuringAndLayout.html).

You can also wrap the whole thing with `Row` and get rid of the `List` braces (modifying the list structure a little first).

## TogglerBar

In case you're open to alternatives, `TogglerBar` could be used instead, but you may already know that.

```
z = {};
{TogglerBar[Dynamic[z], labelList], Dynamic[resultingList = Sort@z]}
```

[image: TogglerBar]

To get the variables, you can use the following:

```
z2 = {};
{TogglerBar[Dynamic[z2], {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}], 
 Dynamic[resultingList = varList[[Sort@z2]]]}
```

Comment: I actually ended up using `ToggleBar` and `Sort` myself, as you suggest, after I discovered those functions. Thanks for pointing out, though!